# Why declare an object by its inherited abstract class instead of its own class

Tags: c#, inheritance, object, polymorphism, abstract-class

```
public abstract class Character
{
    protected Weapon weapon;

    public string Name;
    public int Health = 10;
    public int Strength;

    public Character()
    {
    }

    public void Attack()
    {
        weapon.useweapon();
    }
}

public class Warrior : Character
{
    public Warrior()
    {
        weapon = new Sword();
        Health = 10;
        Strength = 25;
    }

    public void SetWeapon(Weapon newweapon)
    {
        weapon = newweapon;
    }

}

public class Wizard : Character
{
    public Wizard()
    {
        weapon = new Spell();
        Health = 15;
        Strength = 10;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is an abstract Character class and two Character subclasses. In this program, only the warrior can change weapon. Now, I'm not looking to discuss the code itself, what I want to know is, in my implementation code why would I use this:

```
Character Zizo = new Warrior();
Character Hang = new Wizard();
```

Instead of -

```
Warrior Zizo = new Warrior();
Wizard Hang = new Wizard();
Zizo.SetWeapon(new Axe()); //I can only use this method in this implementation
```

What is the difference between the two and what benefit do I get by declaring the object by the abstract class?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a firm grasp of OO concepts.  May be worth investing some time in reading a book on the subject.

Comment: Like to tell me why you think so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Client code should use the minimally required interface or abstract class definition. You do this primarily to keep code more loosely-coupled. In your example, if the calling code only ever needed to `Attack()` but is not concerned with how that's carried out, implemented, or what particular type (e.g. `Warrior`, `Wizard`, etc) is doing the attacking then it should use the `abstract Character` class.

When it **necessarily** must have knowledge of a particular implementation or concrete class, then it is appropriate to explicitly make use of one.

Comment: Even better an IAttack interface should be enough

Answer (score 3):

What you get is the ability to write code that can interact with any publicly exposed `Character` type member on any character type regardless of what it is.

Ex:

```
public void AttackAndHeal(Character character)
{
    character.Attack();
    character.Health++;
}
```

---

```
Warrior zizo = new Warrior();
Wizard hang = new Wizard();

AttackAndHeal(zizo);
AttackAndHeal(hang);
```

Comment: The inheritance allows this. What I want to know is why declare the as Character?

Comment: Actually it's not inheritance but rather polymorphism. Inheritance simply allows you to derive types from a parent. Polymorphism is what allows a type to be treated as another type (it's parent or an implemented interface). That aside, if you're directly instantiating a concrete type and assigning it to a local variable, there's no benefit to using the parent class. If you're working with methods, composite types, factory methods, dependency injection, generics, etc etc, there's plenty of benefit to using parent types.

Answer (score 1):

If you know always that you will use them like that there is no need. But often you want to abstract away the type of character and perform only the actions that are implenmted by all characters.

Let's assume that someone drops an H bomb in the middle of the screen. You won't care if your characters are Wizards or Warriors() they'll all be death, so you only need to call Kill or whatever method you have.

Comment: You don't need to sign your posts. I've made that edit for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a generic collection of `Warrior` and `Wizard` and reuse any members of the `Character` class

```
var characters = new List<Character>();
characters.Add(new Warrior());
characters.Add(new Wizard());
foreach (var c in characters)
{
    //use members exposed by c
}
```

Comment: Like I said, I'm not looking for improvements on the code, just an explanation. Thanks anyway...

Comment: @Zizo47 I don't believe he was talking about an improvement, just an example of when you'd want to treat your objects as their abstract type.  When you want to perform some operation on a collection of them.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring `Zizo` as a `Character`, you can now assign any type of `Character` object to `Zizo`.  Unfortunately, this will also limit you to calling only properties and functions declared explicitly for `Character`.  In order to call anything on `Zizo` specific to `Warrior`, you would need to cast it first.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a regular method (i.e. not overidden) of the same name on the base class and the child class then typing the variable of the object as the base class will cause the method on the base class to be chosen if the method is called. That might be a reason to type it as a character if your looking for that behavior. If you add the warrior to a List or pass it in to a method requiring a Character as a parameter then it's automatically casted to Character (i think), so typing a warrior as Character might make the code less error prone if you are just going to be adding it to list or doing anything else requiring a Character type.